# Solving a series in the proof of the expectation of the binomial distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am studying the expectations and variances of the most common distributions.
For the binomial distribution the mean is equal to $np$.

Considering $p$ and $q$ independent variables and $0<p,q<1$. The proof starts with $m =\sum_{k=0}^{n} k · \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}$ and I don't understand why this equals to $= p \frac{d}{dp}(p+q)^n$

With the binomial theorem $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k} = (p+q)^n$.

But I can't see how do you get the $p$ and the derivative $\frac{d}{dp} (p+q)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(p+q\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $p$ on both sides we find:

$$n\left(p+q\right)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kp^{k-1}q^{n-k}$$

Multiplying with $p$ on both sides we find:

$$np\left(p+q\right)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kp^{k}q^{n-k}$$

If $p+q=1$ then this equality can be written as:

$$np=\mathbb{E}X$$

Where $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$.

---

**Edit**:

I cannot withhold myself from reaching you an alternative route.

It is a *very good thing* to keep in mind that a random variable $X$
binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$ can be written as:

$$X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$$ where the $X_{i}$ are iid and [Bernouilli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)-$p$
distributed. There are $n$ experiments. $X_i$ takes value $1$ if there is a 'success' and value $0$ if there is a 'failure'.

Then: $$\mathbb{E}X_{i}=1\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=1\right)+0\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=1\right)=p$$
and making use of the linearity of expectation we find:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}X_{1}=p+\cdots+p=np$$